# Automatic Smooth Resize Transitions - A Problem with Storyboards

Tags: c#, silverlight, storyboard

I have been trying for some time to create a class/series of classes that, upon detecting a resize in a related object, attempts to halt the resize of the object and create a smooth resize animation for it.
However, I have always had a problem with the objects 'flickering' on the screen for a second at the target size before the animation kicks in.

Long story short, after some serious debugging and self-doubt, I am under the impression that calling `Storyboard.Begin()` does not affect the target value until the *next clock tick*.  I presume that this has something to do with `Storyboard.Seek()` not occuring until the next clock tick.  ([See the MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190534%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)).  And as such, the object adopts its new height for a single frame before the animation kicks in which pulls it back to the starting height.

I have spent a long time trying to get this working because it's not nearly as simple as it seems.  I can't set `FrameworkElement.Height` to the `e.PreviousSize.Height` in a `FrameworkElement.SizeChanged` event handler, because that affects the 'true' height of the object.  As an example of why this doesn't work, is if something changes the 'true' height of the object while the animation is playing, then re-setting `FrameworkElement.Height` to the target height that was collected when the animation began could set it as an incorrect, out-dated value.

There's more things I've tried, and I'm sure they'll come up as answers arrive, but any ideas you have will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Might be completely different from what you're trying to do, but have you tried extending / modifying / taking apart ExtendedVisualStateManager's FluidLayout functionality, which handles similar situations relatively well?

Comment: @dain - It is almost exactly what I want, however it doesn't work when the `VisualState` for collapsed or expanded is contained within each instance's style. In one case there are four instances of a control on the screen, and the `ExtendedVisualStateManager` only works if the container for the four instances contains the states, which is not possible in this case. (I hope that makes sense.)

Furthermore, I also have to deal with controls that change size due to a change in content, not a change in state. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd probably have better luck by creating a layout container that handles the resize of the child objects, something like [Robby Ingebretsen's Animated Panel](http://nerdplusart.com/animatedpanel).

Comment: Thanks Bryant. Solved this one long ago, but it was in the same direction as Robby Ingebretsen's solution, so I'll tick yours.
A couple of MAJOR problems with his solution though.  The biggest being that measuring to infinity on both height and width can result in massive layout problems.