# Begin Storyboard too late (Silverlight)

Tags: silverlight, storyboard

I have a silverlight application in a storyboard that starts before loading my second page, the problem is that the StoryBase starts too late, I need to start faster, I guess this is happening because my second page is too full of controls such as calendar, image, know if there is any way to start faster or before my storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is similar to your problem, but I had a similar problem myself: [Automatic Smooth Resize Transitions - A Problem with Storyboards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139692/automatic-smooth-resize-transitions-a-problem-with-storyboards).
In Silverlight, the `Storyboard.Begin()` starts a clock tick after you call it, and thus can cause problems.  Hope it helps if you're still having the problem!